# Peut-on dire « Je passe par chez moi avant de vous rejoindre. » ?

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, indications-de-lieu

> Je passe **par chez moi** avant de vous rejoindre.

Bien que la tournure semble grammaticalement correcte (et est très usitée, entre autres, en Savoie), le « par chez moi » me chiffonne un peu. Ai-je raison ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Effectivement, la tournure semble correcte grammaticalement. On peut passer par chez soi, comme on peut passer par la Lorraine (pour reprendre la fameuse expression), ou passer par le couloir.
Ceci dit, cela peut sembler incorrect car « chez moi » ne fait pas partie de l'itinéraire. On ne passe pas par chez soi comme un chemin alternatif pour rejoindre une destination. Il s'agit ici plutôt d'un détour, d'une étape. Dire « il faut que je passe chez moi d'abord » me semble donc plus approprié.

Je n'ai pas de preuve de ce que j'avance, c'est simplement le ressenti que j'ai sur le problème.

Comment: Je partage cet avis. Avec "avant de", cela implique que l'on va faire un arrêt chez soi. Si la phrase était "Je passe par chez moi pour vous rejoindre", elle serait plus correcte, car elle indique bien l'itinéraire, et non un arrêt/détour... si on veut effectivement faire un arrêt, on dirait donc plutôt "il faut que je passe chez moi avant de vous rejoindre"...

Comment: Je ne partage pas cet avis. "Je passe par chez moi pour vous rejoindre" et "il faut que je passe chez moi d'abord/avant de vous rejoindre" sont également correctes mais ne donnent pas la même information. La phrase initiale se contente de déclarer un itinéraire, et pour moi elle le fait de façon simple et correcte.

Comment: Je pense qu'utiliser "par chez moi" pour dire "faire un détour par chez moi" est un abus de langage.

Answer (score 3):

Les deux tournures sonnent correctement à mon oreille:

- Je passe chez moi avant de vous rejoindre.
- Je passe par chez moi avant de vous rejoindre.

Je pense utiliser les deux vraiment indistinctement.